# all non-empty sublists partitionings of a list

Tags: code-golf, tips, python, set-partitions

I had to write a code for finding all non-empty sublists partitionings of a list:

```
def f(s):
    if s:
        for j in range(1,len(s)+1):
            for p in f(s[j:]):
                yield [s[:j]]+p
    else:
        yield []
```

I managed to shorten it (for Python 3.4+) to:

```
def f(s, p=[]):
    if s:
        for j in range(1,len(s)+1):
            yield from f(s[j:],p+[s[:j]])
    else:
        yield p
```

using **yield from** and an accumulator argument `p` (prefix).

Any suggestions on how to shorten it even more?

Example output:

```
>>> for p in f([1,2,3,4]): print(p)
...
[[1], [2], [3], [4]]
[[1], [2], [3, 4]]
[[1], [2, 3], [4]]
[[1], [2, 3, 4]]
[[1, 2], [3], [4]]
[[1, 2], [3, 4]]
[[1, 2, 3], [4]]
[[1, 2, 3, 4]]
>>>
```

Comment: For starters, you can use single char variable names and drop a bunch of whitespace

Comment: Can we answer with code in other languages, too? This would work pretty well as a language agnostic challenge.

Comment: @JanDvorak This is asking for help in golfing the python program.

Comment: @okx hence my trying to convert this into a regular challenge via my comment. The answer would carry over just fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## 66 bytes

```
p=lambda l:[q+[l[i:]]for i in range(len(l))for q in p(l[:i])]or[l]
```

If the last part is changed from `[l]` to `[[]]`, then it can also be used with tuples or strings, in addition to lists.

Comment: [Try it online](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#JcgxCsMwDADAuX6FRot6adLJ0B9oyC40OCQpAlcxJoH83sXkxmvTJ6ffvCSgyOXJxBpFtr2CghrUZN/V59U8IfYtfSdPHFVQ9sokrv91v1o5D48Y3aNUtQOu1vgVhjCGt/wB)