# (Can I) Add parentheses to make this true

Tags: code-golf, math, arithmetic, decision-problem

I saw this recent Puzzling question:

#### [Add parentheses to make this true](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/51818/add-parentheses-to-make-this-true)

And saw that [one answer used a Python script to try all possibilities](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/51855).

Your challenge is, given an expression (as a string) and an integer, is to make a program that can tell whether you can add parens to make the expression equal the integer.

For example, if the expression is `1 + 2 * 3` and the integer is `9`, than you can add parens like `(1 + 2) * 3`, which equals 9, so the output should be truthy. But if the expression is `1 + 2 - 3 * 4 / 5` and the integer is `9999999999999`, you can't add any amount of parens to make that equal `9999999999999`, so the output should be falsey.

Note that the integer input may be positive or negative, but the expression will only contain positive integers. In fact, the expression will always match `(\d+ [+*/-] )+ \d` (regex). In other words, no parens, no exponents, just `+`, `-`, `*` and `/`. Standard operator order (`*` and `/`, then `+` and `-`).

More test cases:

```
1 + 2 - 3 * 4 / 9 and -1 -> truthy, ((1 + 2) - (3 * 4)) / 9
10 - 9 * 8 - 7 * 6 - 5 * 4 - 3 * 2 - 2 * 1 and 1, falsey, see linked question
10 + 9 - 8 * 7 + 6 - 5 * 4 + 3 - 2 * 1 and 82 -> truthy, (10 + (9 - 8)) * 7 + (6 - 5) * 4 + 3 - 2 * 1
34 + 3 and 15 -> falsey
1 + 2 + 5 + 7 and 36 -> falsey
1 / 10 * 3 + 3 / 10 * 10 and 6 -> truthy, (1/10*3+3/10)*10
```

Any questions?

You may output the expression with parenthesis if it is possible, for instance `(10 + (9 - 8)) * 7 + (6 - 5) * 4 + 3 - 2 * 1` for the last test case. I would prefer this over just a truthy value, but it is up to you. Using `2(5)` for multiplication is not allowed, only `*`.

Comment: `/` is float division , right?

Comment: @Rod yes, it is.

Comment: You should have a test case that requires a non-integer intermediate result to be used.

Comment: You should add a test case where division by zero might occur, like `3 / 2 - 1 - 1 and 2 -> 3 / (2 - 1) - 1`

Answer (score 2):

## Python 2, <s>286</s> <s>285</s> 282 bytes

```python
from fractions import*
P=lambda L:[p+[L[i:]]for i in range(len(L))for p in P(L[:i])]or[L]
x,y=input()
x=x.split()
for p in P(['Fraction(%s)'%e for e in x[::2]]):
 try:print 1/(eval(''.join(sum(zip(eval(`p`.replace("['","'(").replace("']",")'")),x[1::2]+[0]),())[:-1]))==y)
 except:0
```

[**Try it online**](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#VZBNj5swEIbP9a8YUa1sB0iA7CcV15447N1CWgcmjbcGLJvskv7vnlM7QW16QIOfd57xyK6Koui8t2MPeyvbSY2DA9Wb0U4r8lpp2e86CXUpTCxqocqm2Y8WFKgBrBx@INM4sJrzQE2gr6wWpWp4M1pRN2ROTpUazHFinMzVvHZGq/B/0y/o9@Vmduc4vUMIIYZwFmVZNA0vCUz2VBqrhgnyDcMPqRml6/dRDcwde/ZLmSt8M29ri0bLFlkkaJRElEX8H6KNR5xGnCezyMP0WGQNTxjnokzzhvOqOnECOLdopjI7@@f5a9OQ0eRSvu0syp@UxxS1w2W1jJKvQJcI5NDB/ykc5AfCDnEA2XXYwTSC1Hr8hP6oJ2U0woRuglY6dIR8HpQneUm@4Iwtc/xMc4ihgBS2sIJ72MALhQTSnNA88/TF02dfn3x99PXh0nXtDlbhax6MqxB7IfXCygvxjRB74ab5uSB0e6EX9YEsW8S@PYanALePAW7AD115OQxYDnkWch8HEnbIwxdY8XsY01a2B/wD)

#### Explanation:

This version will print all of the working expressions (with the `Fraction` objects).

```python
from fractions import*
# Sublist Partitions (ref 1)
P=lambda L:[p+[L[i:]]for i in range(len(L))for p in P(L[:i])]or[L]
x,y=input()
x=x.split()
# Convert all numbers to Fractions for division to work
n=['Fraction(%s)'%e for e in x[::2]]
# Operators
o=x[1::2]
# Try each partition
for p in P(n):
    # Move parens to be inside strings
    n=eval(`p`.replace("['","'(").replace("']",")'"))
    # Alternate numbers and operators (ref 2)
    x=''.join(sum(zip(n,o+[0]),())[:-1])
    # Prevent division by zero errors
    try:
        # Evaluate and check equality
        if eval(x)==y:print x
    except:0
```

[**Try it online**](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#TY3BasQgFEXX8SsegUFfJ5NO0p3gtqssZi/C2KkZLImKcYrpz6exFNrFhcvhcu42Rj/DGPUtWe8WsHPwMT2Ri5j0/PauYeAyHOUgLVdq9BEsWAdRu7thk3FsQCw0FHphg@RWofJRDorkZhXWhUdiSLLI7RImW7oTkr7@HrLDgvRgoDhMcWTJea8U8SLLrlTyT@@Qk8oJ86kndg3XNpow6ZthtaR1U1NW4x@iakdIa0RSZUFp@@GtY8tjZl82MNf4ozwrbBii5KdO7asU111f2RF@DjIKsfIQrUuQSWXyzYTEz9tGX@AZejhBV0Khgf4b)

#### References:

1. [Partitioning function](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/53046/34718)
2. [Alternating zip](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3682033/2415524)

<sub>*Saved 3 bytes thanks to Felipe Nardi Batista*</sub>

Comment: 1- Can you use python3 (`/` is float division) and drop all `fractions` uses? 2 - What about divisions by 0?

Comment: @Rod No, you can't. Float division is the reason it's required.

Comment: What's the reason then?

Comment: oh, rounding issues

Comment: I fixed the division by zero problem. It still worked for any example where the solution came before the division by zero, but I did find a test case that broke it. It's the last test case in my test suite.

Comment: [golfed a bit](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#VZBNj5swEIbP9a8YUa1sB0iA7CcV15447N1CWgcmjbcGLJvskv7vnlM7QW16QIOfd57xyK6Koui8t2MPeyvbSY2DA9Wb0U4r8lpp2e86CXUpTCxqocqm2Y8WFKgBrBx@INM4sJrzQE2gr6wWpWp4M1pRN2ROTpUazHFinMzVvHZGq/B/0y/o9@Vmduc4vUMIIYZwFmVZNA0vCUz2VBqrhgnyDcMPqRml6/dRDcwde/ZLmSt8M29ri0bLFlkkaJRElEX8H6KNR5xGnCezyMP0WGQNTxjnokzzhvOqOnECOLdopjI7@@f5a9OQ0eRSvu0syp@UxxS1w2W1jJKvQJcI5NDB/ykc5AfCDnEA2XXYwTSC1Hr8hP6oJ2U0woRuglY6dIR8HpQneUm@4Iwtc/xMc4ihgBS2sIJ72MALhQTSnNA88/TF02dfn3x99PXh0nXtDlbhax6MqxB7IfXCygvxjRB74ab5uSB0e6EX9YEsW8S@PYanALePAW7AD115OQxYDnkWch8HEnbIwxdY8XsY01a2B/wD)